# Spring boot rest request data type validation

Tags: spring-boot

I am doing validation for request object in spring boot rest. I have to validate data type of request. The request has multiple boolean values and trying to validate if string in passed for boolean data type.
I have handling HttpMessageNotReadableException in my ControllerAdvice class and sending list of error message. But in my response only first field is throwing exception. If clue ,please help.

Answer (score 0):

> @Vishnu Dubey use this .....

```
  @RestControllerAdvice
        public class ServiceControllerAdvice {
            private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceControllerAdvice.class);
            @ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
            @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            public ServiceResponse<?> constraintViolationException(final ConstraintViolationException ex) {
                log.error("Validation failed", ex);
                final ServiceResponse<?> response = new ServiceResponse<>(-1);
                final Error error = new Error();
                error.setCode("PS01");
                error.setContext(ex);
                error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
                response.setError(error);
                return response;
            }
}
```